# How do I remove "<div>", "<br>" and "</div>" from a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, string, replace

EDIT: I am using jsPDF and contenteditable paragraphs. If I hit enter a few times while editing the paragraph on the user's side in html and then convert it to PDF, instead of the lines moving down, it shows `"<div><br></div>"` for each time the user hit enter while editing the paragraph. I have code that removes extra white spaces, nbsp, etc. but I can't seem to get rid of the aforementioned. See attached image: [IMAGE1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuJdN.png)

`"&nbsp;"` and `"&nbsp; "` showed up too, but I was able to remove them all by writing the attached code snippet, but I cannot seem to figure out how to remove `"<div>"`, `"<br>"` and `"</div>"` from my string output which appears in the PDF.

```
$(this).html($(this).html().replace(/&nbsp; /gi,' '));
$(this).html($(this).html().replace(/&nbsp;/gi,''));
$(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\s+/g,' ').trim());
```

Comment: Could you please add an example input and expected output? It's not really clear to me, if I remove `“<div>”, “<br>” and “</div>”` from your string, all you'll get is an empty string. Probably you can't find an answer because you need to ask a better question :)

Comment: Do you want to remove all HTML from the string, or just that specific sequence?

Comment: Parse as actual elements, get the elements with `.querySelectorAll()` and `remove()` them

Comment: Maybe the better question would be to ensure that those elements don't get added to the output in the first place? If you show us the code that is generating it, we could help.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I got a feeling that is from WordPress or similar CMS generates that kind of output on each new line..

Comment: It looks like the kind of markup generated by a `<div contenteditable="true">`...

Comment: Edited! Sorry for the vague first draft, very new to this. Any help is appreciated!